# Parallax.js moves my css-positioned elements

Tags: javascript, css, gsap, parallax.js

I'm starting out experimenting with Parallax.js and having a problem:

I lay out some clouds in the sky, and position their 'top' position using CSS in such a way that they're distributed over the sky (I've also tried this using Javascript and Greensock GSAP, in this case setting their 'y').  However init'ing Parallax.js just wipes their positions clear and sets them all on top of each other.

I've gone through the config variables in Parallax.js and tried changing some, but it doesn't help.'

What am I not understanding?

Also, is it possible to animate Parallax.js positioned elements using GSAP?  That is, have them move across the screen as well as being affected by Parallax.ja?

Comment: please post the code so that one can help you

Comment: instead of using `top:` use `transform: translateY(...);` and see what happens.  This is only based on your story here since you haven't provided any code

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem too, here's an answer for future Google searches.

For some reason parallax.js adds 'position: absolute' to your .layer elements. In the non-jquery version - I just commented out the following on **line 289**.

```
// Configure Layer Styles
for (var i = 0, l = this.layers.length; i < l; i++) {
  var layer = this.layers[i];
  if (this.transform3DSupport) this.accelerate(layer);
  // layer.style.position = i ? 'absolute' : 'relative'; // nope
  // layer.style.display = 'block'; // nope
  // layer.style.left = 0; // nope
  // layer.style.top = 0; // nope
```

Comment: This works great! Note it's on line 704 for version 3.1.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem myself last week and figured I'd leave an answer for all you googlers out there. Though I don't have the poster's code at hand I have a pretty good guess.

```
<ul>
  <li class='layer sky' data-depth=0.0></li>
  <li class='layer cloud1' data-depth=0.4></li>

....

 .cloud1 {
  background-image: url('...');
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 300px;
 }
```

The `layer` element is set to 0,0 by parallax.js as you noted, you need to instead define objects *within* each layer.

```
   <ul>
  <li class='layer' data-depth=0.0><div class='sky'></div></li>
  <li class='layer' data-depth=0.4><div class='clouds1'></div></li>
```